# Community's website wasn't updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, community-user

[image]

Should be [meta.stackexchange.com](http://meta.stackexchange.com), not [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Ya dun good Community. Ya dun... _wait_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ho hum.

So high priority it got fixed immediately.

That it was super easy to do had nothing to do with that.